# DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I have this function on javaScript, and works on Firefox, but on google chrome not

```
function sendInfo(userId, Code) {
            // text with all info to send to controller
            var values = {
                "token": Code,
                "code": userId
            }

            // POST THE CHANGE HERE TO THE DATABASE
            var url = "WSHolFacebook.asmx/saveToken";
            $.post(url, values, function (data) {
                if (window.ActiveXObject) { return data.xml; }
                var xmlString = XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
                var xml = xmlString,
                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                $title = $xml.find("string");
                var texto = $title.text();
                if ($title.text() == "Success") {
                    window.location = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["successUrl"].ToString() %>'
                }
                else {
                    window.location = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["errorUrl"].ToString() %>'
                }
            })
        }
```

the error in chrome it is:

> *Uncaught TypeError: DOM object constructor cannot be called as a
>   function.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
var xmlString = XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
```

to

```
var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
```

The reason it throws the error is because you are trying to invoke XMLSerializer as a function instead of instantiating it.

Comment: that it is, thanks man, i lost a lot of time on that question, and because a new!!!! thanks again